# What is the Database for openID and with registration form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, openid, dotnetopenauth

I have a registration form and login Also use openid to signin.
Do I have to use same database table for login and openid?
What is the database for openid? or
What datas do we capture for openid signin?
I have this registration table:
username:
Password:
confirmpassword:

Login with Username and password

We dont need to create password when we login with openid.

so we need to use 3 different database there? :/ Please help me, I use mvc3/razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an additional field to your userLogin information table for storing the openID identifier.

On your backend you'll have 2 authentication points. One for user basic login (email/password) and another for openID.